# Display variable value in Jupyter cell placeholder which can be updated from another function

Tags: python, ipywidgets

What is the best way to display variable value while executing a function using the same output object, preferably ipywidgets. Currently I'm only able to display the last value of a variable.

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
import  time
label = widgets.Label(value='Status:')
def test ():    
    global status
    label.value = "Executing"
    time.sleep(2)
    label.value = "Done"
test()
label
```

Answer (score 0):

Display the widget before running the function?

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
import  time
label = widgets.Label(value='Status:')
def test ():    
    global status
    label.value = "Executing"
    time.sleep(2)
    label.value = "Done"
display(label)
test()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to display something in a single placeholder and see it updates. ( Something like a progress bar). Use the [Output](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Output%20Widget.html) widget provided. It should be something like this.

```
out = widgets.Output()
with out:
   display("starting")
display(out)
```

In your function add like this.

```
def update_something():
   do_something()
   out.clear_output() 
   with out:
      display("done")
```

This will update the value already printed in your output cell with the latest value.